# Render inside a for loop express.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, express

Hi all I am trying to render a view inside of a for loop. Is this the correct way to do such a thing in express.js? The only thing that needs to change is the second property. 'subTitle'. I am able to console.log the tweets no issue just cannot render the view.

```
 twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline',{user_id:xxxxxxxx, screen_name:'xxxxxxx'},                      
               function (error, params, response){                                                              
                    if(error) throw error;
                    for(var text in params){
                        console.log(params[text].text);//+params[].text);
                        res.render('index', { 
                         title: 'Home Page',
                         subTitle: params[text].text
                        });
                    }    
 });
```

Comment: I ended up doing `var output` in the route and just outputting the `params[text].text from the for loop to output by `output += params[text].text`

Answer (score 1):

You can't render more than once when using `render()` in that way since by default Express renders the output and then automatically sends the response back to the client.

If you want to render output without automatically sending a response, you can pass in a callback as a third argument to `render()`. The callback is passed error and output string arguments. Example:

```
res.render('index', { 
  title: 'Home Page',
  subTitle: params[text].text
}, function(err, out) {
  // `out` is the rendered content
});
```

Comment: So I can add the for loop inside the second callback? params[text] is not defined until the for loop is exectuted